# Understand aes cbc IV

Tags: aes

When I use AES CBC, the encrypt function needs to get an input-buffer to encrypt + key + IV?

Is IV like one more key, or IV is generated by the key (so the encrypt function only needs to get the input-buffer to encrypt and the key)?

Answer (score 1):

An IV is used to make sure that the same input (plain text) results in a different output (cipher text) even if the same encryption key is used - which can be guaranteed if a different IV is used all the time. The IV does not really be kept secret and insofar it is not comparable with the encryption key. But it should be as unpredictable as possible which means it should have uniform randomness (no IV is more probable than any other).

Answer (score 0):

The [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) **must be** a [cryptographically random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) of exactly 128 bits. Being a nonce, each IV must never be used more than once.

Also, please use a cryptographic library that hides this configuration stuff, because it is very easy to make mistakes.

Comment: You are missing the important requirement than an IV be _random_ as well as single use. While the terms are sometimes mistakenly used interchangeably, nonces are not necessarily random, but IVs _must_ be random.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald You are of course right, thanks for your comment. I guess I wrote my answer too fast. I edited my answer accordingly.